# How can I emit text on the command line with a strike-though effect using JLine?

Tags: java, text, syntax, console, jline

I'm using JLine for a console application and I would like to emit text with a strike-through effect.

Is this possible with JLine and how would I do it?

Are there any platform-specific concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your terminal supports it this is how you would do it:

```
ANSIBuffer buffer = new ANSIBuffer();
buffer.attrib("Text", 9);
System.out.println(buffer.getAnsiBuffer());
```

You can also use Jansi:

```
Ansi ansi = new Ansi();
ansi.a(Ansi.Attribute.STRIKETHROUGH_ON);
ansi.a("Striked");
ansi.reset();
System.out.println(ansi);
```

Comment: What's the difference between those two?

Comment: ANSIBuffer is a class from JLine 0.9.x (removed in JLine 2), and Ansi is a class from the Jansi project (http://jansi.fusesource.org) used in combination with JLine 2

Comment: JLine2? Mhhh. What happened to development there?